# check to see if first element is <h3>, if so addClass. if not, do nothing

Tags: jquery

I would like to add an if statement to the below code that checks to see if the first element within the div (#content) is a H3 tag.

- If so, add the class (removeline) to the first H3 within the div.
- If not, do nothing.

How would I got about adding this if statement to the following?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Fix first Header tags in content
    $("#content h3").first().addClass("removeline");            
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content>h3:first-child").addClass("removeline");            
});
```

This finds a child `<h3>` that is *also* a [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) inside `#content`...if the selector doesn't match any elements, it'll have no effect.

Comment: Why do I bother with these `[jquery]` questions! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var content = $('#content');

    if (content.find(' > *:first').is('h3')) {   
        content.find('h3:first').addClass("removeline");            
    }

});
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/NMy2Z/)